# What is the equation of time period for a bent wire pendulum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, experimental-physics, harmonic-oscillator

Just like there is a formula for time periods of a simple pendulum and a spring pendulum. Is there a formula for the time period of bent wire pendulum? There does not seem to be much research done on it on the internet.
I could only find the following website: https://zylsciencefan.wordpress.com/2012/12/25/analysis-of-a-bent-wire-pendulum/

Comment: The blog post you linked to gives a formula for the period. So why are you asking for a formula?

Comment: Yes, I know that. But, I just want to find out what other factors effect the time period of the pendulum. Im also looking for other resources since the blog was the only one i could ifnd

Comment: Why do you think there would be other factors?

Comment: At this point, I am not sure if there are other factors. I am trying to find out the other factors, if there are any